# Convert an Object with List<String> to ImmutableList

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, guava, immutablelist

My Object :

```
List<Test>
.
.
.
Test {
String name;
String salary;
List<String> nickNames;}
```

I would like to convert this list to an ImmutableList
(ie)

```
ImmutableList<Test>
```

> where nickNames in Test must also be converted into an ImmuatableList

I could do something like this

```
listOfObjects()
.stream()
.map(obj -> {obj.setNickNames(ImmutableList.copyOf(obj.getNickNames)); return obj;})
.collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
```

But is there any other cleaner way to achieve this ?

Comment: What's the point of that, if `Test` is a mutable object? The result will still be mutable. You'll need an `ImmutableTest`, otherwise this is meaningless.

Comment: I'm populating this list from ConfiguraitonProperties. I could not make Test immutable since it is also populated from @ConfigurationProperties. The goal is to make both lists -> ImmutableList